# 1.14.4 How to detect bow pulling stages?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In texture packs there is something like ***bow***, ***bow_pulling_0***, ***bow_pulling_1*** and ***bow_pulling_2***.
So I was wondering if I could do:

```
/execute as @a[nbt={id:"minecraft:bow_pulling_0"}]
```

or like any tag that I can use so I can instantly pull my bow?

Also if you know any thread that works for accelerating arrow speed in the right direction let me know ty.

Answer (score 1):

The bow pull stages are not detectable or settable by commands. The closest you can get is a crossbow with Quick charge 100 (or more) or retexturing something else (for example a snowball) and spawning an arrow with the right motion when the item is used (like [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/339637/how-to-use-coordinate-systems-for-motion-nbt/339670?r=SearchResults&s=1|27.1388#339670)).