# Ender Dragons spawned with commands center their behavior at (0,0). Can this be changed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to create a 1.16.1 adventure map which includes an Ender Dragon boss fight. I've figured out how to summon a dragon in the Overworld that isn't passive, but the problem is that the dragon's perch (which in a normal fight is above the portal, and is the center point for its circling and attack patterns) is at (0,0), which isn't where the boss fight is supposed to take place. I've looked around for a way to tweak the perch point, but I haven't been able to find any way to do it using command blocks or commands. I don't want to get into modding or data packs if possible, as I have effectively no knowledge of how to create them. If it's not possible, I'm capable of substituting a different boss for the fight, but if it's possible to use an Ender Dragon given these circumstances I'd prefer to incorporate it.

Is it possible to shift the "perch" for an Ender Dragon spawned with the /summon command away from (0,0) using command blocks? If so, how is this done?

Comment: Not confident enough to post an answer, but I'm pretty sure this isn't possible. Of course, you could work around this by moving your boss fight into the end, if you aren't using 0,0 in the end for some other purpose.

Comment: I'm not using the end, but moving the fight there probably wouldn't fix my particular problem due to other issues irrelevant to this topic. I'll probably figure out some sort of substitute instead. Seems a bit dumb that they limit the dragon's versatility like that...

Comment: According to https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Exit_portal#Trivia: "If an End Portal is built in Creative mode in The End or generated through custom world generation, then it also acts as an Exit Portal". The exit portal is what you call the "perch". I'm not sure if this will change things, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: You can see that in the overworkd the ender dragon will perch at (0,0,0)

Comment: And glitches itself through bedrock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, except if you replace the natural movement of the dragon with teleports. You could smooth it out by also setting the `Motion` tag fittingly, but that's a bit [complicated](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/339670/171580).