# How do I use tildes and carets in the teleport command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need help with using these symbols because the wiki isn't helping me. Also, when I use this ^ in a repeating command block, it doesn't update where I am looking at.<sup>[1]</sup> Could someone help me? <sup>[1]</sup>Especially this one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the basics of commands in Minecraft Java Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354614/what-are-the-basics-of-commands-in-minecraft-java-edition)

Comment: See also [How to use ^^^ coordinate systems for motion nbt](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/339637/185203)

Comment: The second part of the question still needs to be answered, moderator!

Comment: The second part of the question doesn't contain enough detail to be answered without specifying exactly what command you are using, what it should do, and what it currently does. And I am not a [moderator](/help/site-moderators).

Comment: Please see [What to do before asking a minecraft-commands question?](https://meta.arqade.com/q/13507/4797)

Answer (score 1):

The tilde ~ coordinate is relative to the player's current world location. So if I teleport a player to ~ ~1 ~, then they will be teleported 1 block up from their current position.

Using the carrot ^ will be relative to the current local direction of the player. So a ^X will be towards the left, while ^-X will be towards the right, while ^Z will be forward in front of the player and ^-Z will be behind. ^Y is up, ^-Y is down. So if a player is teleported ^ ^ ^1, then the player is teleported 1 block in the direction they are looking.